# Snorby-Snort-sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, snort

I am not getting emails from snorby interface. Barnyard2 and snort etc are running fine.
I tried to run manually the daily job but it gives error to "check mail settings".
When i run below command
Snorby::Jobs::SensorCacheJob.new(true).perform

I am getting error as

Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'snorby.event.timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (code: 1055, sql state: 42000, query: SELECT signature FROM event GROUP BY signature ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5, uri: mysql:root@localhostsnorby?database=snorby&path=snorby&adapter=mysql&username

I did some checks and it seems to be related to mysql version upgrade.
I tried to disable "ql_mode=only_full_group_by " bu running below command but the result is the same.
set global sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Please can someone help?
I am running Snorby 2.6.3 and mysql 5.7.17

Comment: Your queries have a smell, because they are using `ORDER BY` while selecting non aggregate columns.  The long term fix is to clean up your queries, such that this error goes away on _all_ versions of MySQL.  The short term fix, which you seem to know, is to turn off `only_full_group_by` mode.  If that isn't working, then you're either doing it wrong, or maybe someone/something is overriding your settings.

Comment: I turned it off as below, but still the error persists. mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                             |

| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)